# How do I change pseudo-classes in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, pseudo-class

I have a clock widget on my website and I want the element to have my custom `:target` animation as soon as it's activated, without changing the hash.
I know, I could just write my code so the `:target` animation is played on the element when the widget is shown but I want to manipulate the element to have the `:target` pseudo-class.
Basically, I want the same effect as using a hash in the URL but without a URL change.
The Firefox DevTools are also based on HTML and JS, right? How do they do it?

Here's my animation in a snippet:

```js
function initialize() {
  // Here should the code be that applies the :target pseudo-class to div#uhr...
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initialize)
```

```css
/* My :target animation */
:target {
    animation-name: hervorhebungWegenHash; 
    animation-duration: 10s; 
    animation-timing-function: linear; 
    animation-fill-mode: both; 
}
@keyframes hervorhebungWegenHash {
    2% {
        color: black;
        background-color: orange;
    }
}
```

```html
<iframe style="position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;width:120px;height:120px;border:1px solid #4682b4;border-radius:50%;pointer-events:none;overflow:hidden;" id="uhr" src="https://www.lampe2020.de/widgets/uhr">&nbsp;</iframe>

<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/46262124/17865928" title="copied 2022-05-26" style="position:absolute;top:125px">This clock widget is also from SO.</a>
```

To see the animation applied, go to [my website](https://www.lampe2020.de#uhr), type "uhr" into the page (no textarea, just on the page). Otherwise you can check it by applying `#page` to my main page. Then the whole block in the middle should be orange and fade out to blue over the course of ~9 seconds.

Update: I've found a workaround but one question remains, out of interest:
How do the DevTools do it?

Comment: You can not "apply" a pseudo class via JS. But what is stopping you to change the selector, so that it applies to elements with a specific class? And then set that class for the element in your initialization function. (_If_ that initialization is even still necessary then ...? Would applying the animation directly via the selector `#uhr` not give you the same result?)

Comment: @CBroe I want it to behave like the URL hash, the `div#uhr` is just one example. I want to be able to mimic the behavior of a URL hash but without affecting the URL.

Comment: How do you define `as soon as it's activated,` in which case does it get activated if it is not by the change of the url? What is the action that activates the clock?

Comment: @t.niese The clock is either activated by the initialization function in the main JS script (/assets/js/index.js) or by a keydown EventHandler which stores the pressed keys in a variable and when it gets an "r" it checks if there's a "uhr" in the variable. If yes it shows/hides the clock, depending on what state it's in.   At least on Firefox 100 it works like intended, the :target animation also plays everytimes the element is shown, even if it already finished playing and was not reloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have eventually found a workaround (not a solution but okay...) myself:

```
function mimicURLHash(hash) {
    if (window.location.hash === '#' + hash) {              // If the hash is also in the URL, remove it.
        if (history.replaceState) {
            history.replaceState("", document.title, window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
        } else {
            window.location.hash = '';
        }
    }
    window.scroll(document.getElementById(hash).getBoundingClientRect().top, document.getElementById(hash).getBoundingClientRect().left);
    document.getElementById(hash).classList.add('target');
}
```

You can see it applied here:

With this I just need to copy the CSS from the `:target {}` to the `.target {}` part. And then the function will be able to mimic a URL hash.

```js
function mimicURLHash(hash) {
    if (window.location.hash === '#' + hash) {              // If the hash is also in the URL, remove it.
        if (history.replaceState) {
            history.replaceState("", document.title, window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
        } else {
            window.location.hash = '';
        }
    }
    window.scroll(document.getElementById(hash).getBoundingClientRect().top, document.getElementById(hash).getBoundingClientRect().left);
    document.getElementById(hash).classList.add('target');
} 

function initialize() {
  mimicURLHash('uhr'); // Normally you would feed window.location.hash to it or put it into a click event handler. 
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initialize)
```

```css
/* My :target animation */
/* // The old CSS, no longer needed for this snippet:
:target {
    animation-name: hervorhebungWegenHash; 
    animation-duration: 10s; 
    animation-timing-function: linear; 
    animation-fill-mode: both; 
}*/
/* This is the CSS we need for this function to work: */
.target {
    animation-name: hervorhebungWegenHash; 
    animation-duration: 10s; 
    animation-timing-function: linear; 
    animation-fill-mode: both; 
}
@keyframes hervorhebungWegenHash {
    2% {
        color: black;
        background-color: orange;
    }
}
```

```html
<iframe style="position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;width:120px;height:120px;border:1px solid #4682b4;border-radius:50%;pointer-events:none;overflow:hidden;" id="uhr" src="https://www.lampe2020.de/widgets/uhr">&nbsp;</iframe>

<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/46262124/17865928" title="copied 2022-05-26" style="position:absolute;top:125px">This clock widget is also from SO.</a>
```